# Error 413 while accessing cookies : Request Entity too large on weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: jquery, cookies, weblogic, session-cookies

I am getting Error 413 - Request entity too large while trying to read data from cookies in my web application.

When I access my application for the first time - the cookies are loaded and I dont face any issue then. But later when I try to reaccess these cookies to read data, I face this error.

On deleting the existing cookies from firebug and launching the application again, I dont face any issue.

My web application is a Java / JSF 2.0 web application running on Weblogic 10.3.6 application server. I use JQuery for client side programming.

Any kind of leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some more info on what kind of operation is being performed/when it happens? e.g. is a POST happening when you get the 413?

Comment: It is a GET Operation

Comment: You may need to play with some of these settings: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28389_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/Corecoreserverserverprotocolshttptitle.html like HTTP Max Message Size